# can't draw on a JPanel after repaint method

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, repaint

I'm experimenting on a GUI that I programmed and I don't understand how I can fix my problem:
My GUI contains a jPanel that on receiving a mouseclick, paints a point with filloval command.

```
private void myPnlMousePressed(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                   
    changed = true;
    p.x = evt.getX();
    p.y = evt.getY();
    drewPoints(p.x, p.y);
} 

private void drewPoints (int x, int y) {
    if (gf == null) {
        gf = (Graphics)myPnl.getGraphics();
    }
    myPointsList.add(new Point(x, y));
    gf.fillOval(x, y, 5, 5);
    xVal.setText("X = " + x);
    yVal.setText("Y = " + y);
}
```

everything works fine but when I want to open an XML file that I created to save all the points it doesn't work.
The problem is that when I use the repaint method on the jPanel after choosing a file, all the points loads fine but the panel can't draw the points.
If I put the repaint method in the open button listener (before the choosing file) it works, but then if the user cancels the open option so the panel stays blank and I don't want to draw the points again.
I think it happens because the repaint process is not finished.
All the points added to a private List.

```
private void OpenFile() {
    try {
        File thisFile;
        JFileChooser of = new JFileChooser();
        int option = of.showOpenDialog(of);

        if (option == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
            thisFileName = of.getSelectedFile().getPath();
            thisFile =  new File(thisFileName);                
            if (!of.getSelectedFile().getName().endsWith(".xml")) {
                String error = "Error, You didn't select XML file";
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, error, "Wrong type of file", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                return;
            }            
            myPnl.repaint();
            myPointsList.clear();
                        ....
                        ....
                        ....
            for (int i = 0; i < pointsList.getLength(); i++) {
                Element point = (Element) pointsList.item(i);
                p.x = Integer.parseInt(point.getElementsByTagName("X").item(0).getTextContent());
                p.y = Integer.parseInt(point.getElementsByTagName("Y").item(0).getTextContent());
                drewPoints(p.x, p.y);
            }
                        ....
```

how can I make it work??

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).  Hard code some data for it to use.

Answer (score 4):

Don't use `gf = (Graphics)myPnl.getGraphics();`, this is not how painting in Swing works.  The `getGraphics` method can return `null` and is nothing more then a snap shot of the last paint cycle, any thing you paint to it will be erased on the next paint cycle (repaint).

Instead, override the `JPanel`s `paintComponent` and put all you painting logic there.  There is an expectation that when called, you are expected to fully re-paint the current state of the component.

See [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for more details about how painting works in Swing

Answer (score 2):

You have to use the `repaint()` and override the `paint()` method:

```
class MyPanel extends JPanel implements MouseListener
{
    private int x;
    private int y;

    public MyPanel() {
        super();
        addMouseListener(this);
    }

    @Override public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) { }

    @Override public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) { }

    @Override public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) { }

    @Override public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) { }

    @Override public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        x = e.getX();
        y = e.getY();
        repaint();
    }

    @Override public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);
        g.fillOval(x, y, 10, 10);
    }
}
```

If you want to draw all points, don't use `x` and `y` but a `list of points`:

```
class MyPanel extends JPanel implements MouseListener
{
    private ArrayList<Point> points = new ArrayList<>();

    public MyPanel() {
        super();
        addMouseListener(this);
    }

    @Override public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) { }

    @Override public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) { }

    @Override public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) { }

    @Override public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) { }

    @Override public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        points.add(new Point(e.getX(), e.getY()));
        repaint();
    }

    @Override public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);
        for (Point p : points)
            g.fillOval(p.getX(), p.getY(), 10, 10);
    }
}
```

where:

```
class Point
{
    private int x;
    private int y;

    public Point(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }
}
```

Then use it:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(400, 400);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    MyPanel myPanel = new MyPanel();

    frame.add(myPanel);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: 1) Class `Point` already exists and we can even get an instance of it from a `MouseEvent` by calling `MouseEvent#getPoint()` method. 2) When we do custom painting we should override `paintComponent()` rather than `paint()`. 3) To repaint the component we should call `repaint()` and not `update()`.

Comment: @dic19 - 1) The `Point` class has been specified to show the user how it is made. 3) You're right, my oversight, just edited.

Comment: Please don't demonstrate overriding paint, it's not the best choice for painting, you should be using paintComponent

Comment: You may also want to do some research into "Initial Threads" in a Swing